# Development environment setup and configuration for web development

Tags: git, zend-framework, development-environment

I know this is stupid question.I am newbie. But me and my friend want to work on a website project. We both are located at few miles from each other. So I want information and steps towards making a smooth working environment for both of us by which we can see updates and results from both of us and watever changes we make to the website. I wanted to know how can we use git(as this will be used for version control), zend framework (we decided to use this one), phpdesigner (our IDE) collectively in developing this site. Also I wanted to know steps and information on how we work locally and push our changes at final product using git. Right now I have all scattered information about git and zend. So if someone would please align all these scattered things and let me know how can we can setup our first development environment.

Also if someone could tell me how to setup development, test, pre-production and production environment.

Dude "m learning " man  :)

Comment: I just removed references to "subversion" and the related tags from your question. You seem to be asking specifically about git, not subversion, and furthermore seem to misunderstand "subversion" to be a generic term for all version control systems. It is not. Subversion is a separate tool in its own right similar to (but predating and with a different use scenario than) git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I use to work collectively. For this you have to use **netbeans** as IDE & need to have **Github** account as you are using git as scm.

1. create account at Github
2. [Create Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/)
3. [Copy your repo url](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)
4. [Create Branch](https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches)
5. [Clone it from netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#github)
6. [Now push, pull or fetch](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#fetch)
7. [Create a pull request before merge](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/)
8. [Merge pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/)

This are the steps I follow for my personal work with working on a team. I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks Arif.I'll try these steps.but i also want some information on working with zend framework and github collectively.I'll dig in more ..!